# How do I know when the last async operation will finish?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, asynchronous

I'm building an app in NodeJs and it involves sending external requests asynchronously. Previously I had one id:

```
# client
function sendAjax(id) {
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "/fsfdsfd",
  data: JSON.stringify({"id": id}),
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  dataType: "json",
}).done(function (data) {
    //.....


# server
app.post("/dsfdsfd", function (req, res, nxt) {
  var id = req.body.id;
  anotherServerClient.sendExternalRequest(id), function(data) {
    //success

    //return the result, but when exactly?
    res.end("ok");
  }, function (e) {

    // error, but when exactly?
    res.end("error");
  });
```

Now I have an array:

```
# client
function sendAjax(ids) {
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "/fsfdsfd",
  data: JSON.stringify({"ids": ids}),
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  dataType: "json",
}).done(function (data) {
    //.....


# server
app.post("/dsfdsfd", function (req, res, nxt) {
  var ids = req.body.ids;
  for (var id in ids) {
    anotherServerClient.sendExternalRequest(id), function(data) {
      //success

      //return the result
      res.end("ok");
    }, function (e) {
      // error
      res.end("error");
    });
  }
}
```

How can I know when the last operation in the loop "for (var id in ids) {" will finish to 
return the result to the client only after that? What's the idiomatic and simple solition?

Comment: Depends on what anotherServerClient.sendExternalRequest is based on. If it uses jQuery, you can wait for multiple requests to finish by passing them to jQuery.when https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/

Comment: @nutrija, jquery on the server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// server
app.post("/dsfdsfd", function (req, res, nxt) {
  var ids = req.body.ids;
  // create output array to collect responses
  var output = [];
  for (var id in ids) {
    anotherServerClient.sendExternalRequest(id, function(data) {
      // on success, push the response to the output array
      output.push(data);
      // check if all responses have come back, and handle send
      // if the length of our output is the same as the list of requests
      if(output.length >= ids.length){
        //return the results array
        res.end("ok");
      }
    }, function (e) {
      // if any api call fails, just send an error back immediately
      res.end("error");
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: It depends on the implementation of the `anotherServerClient.sendExternalRequest` right ?

Comment: Well, should be a pretty general solution. It expects that each external request is async, and calls the success callback. If any external request fails, the response back to the client will be a failure. The return back to the client will be an array of responses instead of a single response.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways to do this, all idiomatic and down to matter of personal taste.

There is a library called [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) that provides help in these kind of operations. It specifically contains methods for going through a collection and doing something asynchronous with each of the items. Check out `forEachOf`, `forEachOfSeries`, `forEachOfLimit` for details.

You can achieve this [using Promises](http://bytearcher.com/articles/es6-promise-then-beginner-tutorial/). Make your API return Promises instead of accepting callbacks. Then create an array of Promises, one for each call and then then wait for all them with Promise.all.

ES6 specification now includes Promises so that is an indication what will be the favorite way in the future.

Comment: get out of here with your libraries and complexity they bring to such a simple task. You're incapable to create a single variable instead of using a library?

Comment: asynchronicity is a complex topic and libraries help to tackle it, welcome to node.js, you must be new here..  i'm not going spend energy commenting on your insulting tone, considering it was towards a person that tried to help you